# Finding which interp one is in

Tags: tcl

I'm debugging some Tcl code which is using child interpreters, and not being familiar with the code, it would be handy to sprinkle some "puts" showing the path to the current interpreter to get a handle on what the code is doing.  Is there a way in Tcl 8.4 to determine which interpreter one is running in?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to just pick the information up (it would violate the isolation principle). But you can pass that information into the sub-interpreters after you create them easily enough:

```
set i [interp create]
$i eval [list set ::myInterpName $i]
```